# How to bind an Observable to a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I'm relatively new to RxSwift. I have an Observable and want to bind it to a UITableView. All examples and solutions I found so far use Observables<[Item]> to bind it to a TableView - but I don't have the result of type Array.

How would I convert my Observable to an Observable<[Item]>? Or how would I use the Observable to show the results in a TableView?

Comment: What exactly is the type of the `Observable` which you want to bind with to a table view? And how do you create this `Observable`? The answer might depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have nice example

```
let items = Observable.just([
                 "First Item",
                 "Second Item",
                 "Third Item"
             ])

             items
             .bindTo(tableView.rx.items) { (tableView, row, element) in
                 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
                 cell.textLabel?.text = "\(element) @ row \(row)"
                 return cell
             }
             .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```